# How can I add SKPhysicsBody to object

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

i have scene with circle , character and triangles.
My character rotating into and outside to my circle and she Passes through the obstacles but she need to Get away from them.

I think that i have problem with the physics of my triangle , i tried to fix it but its not working.

I saw the physics of my triangles and i see that my size triangle (40,40) no match to my outline triangles physics.

[That's how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD1wf.png)

**We can see that the physics body of my character match to your body and my triangle not.**

**The Code:**

```
func AddTriangleToCircle(Circle: SKShapeNode, Location: CGFloat, Inside: Bool) {

    Triangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Triangle.png")

    Triangle.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    Triangle.anchorPoint.y = 0


    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil,298,2)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,149,298)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,0,0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,298,2)

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

    Triangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)


    if Inside == true {
        // Inside Triangle
        Triangle.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
    } else {
        // Outside Triangle
        Triangle.zRotation = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
    }

    Triangle.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:circleRadius)

    let rotationSpeed1 = rotationSpeed + Location;
    var angleRelatedToCircle1 = angleRelatedToCircle;

    angleRelatedToCircle1 -= rotationSpeed1
    Triangle.zRotation -= rotationSpeed1

    Triangle.position.x = circleRadius * cos(angleRelatedToCircle1)
    Triangle.position.y = circleRadius * sin(angleRelatedToCircle1)


    Triangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture:TriangelSKT, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
    Triangle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = triangleCategory
    Triangle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = heroCategory
    Triangle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = heroCategory
    Triangle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    // Set Dynamic to false
    Triangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Circle.addChild(Triangle);
}
```

Comment: You've changed triangle's anchor point (probably because to make node's positioning easier). Anchor point is a visual property, and it has nothing with physics body. Physics body is centered on node's position. Anchor point define how texture is drawn relative to the node. So, use default anchor (0.5,0.5) and position node accordingly.